# SystemData cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse

```
Button Btn; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

    Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);     

    OnClickListener Btn = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);               
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Select an application");    
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);    
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);    
            startActivityForResult(intent, SystemData.VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);              
        }
    };
}
```

Подчёркивает SystemData, почему? Как исправить?

Comment: `Alt+Insert -> Import Class` пробовали ?

Comment: Предлагает только создать класс..

Comment: У вас вообще компилироваться, вроде, не должно. У вас две переменных Btn и обе разного типа и с большой буквы. А должны быть с разными названиями и с маленькой буквы.

Comment: И покажите ссылку на пример откуда вы этот код взяли. Скорее всего нема такого класса и его просто в примере для примера привели.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб,
https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/developing-android-applications-with-voice-recognition-features?language=ru

Comment: А там не все равно, что идет в `requestCode` у `startActivityForResult`, лишь бы с проверкой в `onActivityResult` совпало?